# Client-side automation using PageSpeed Insights - how to transmit results like <URL>_<metric> into Summary(/Aggregate) Report in JMeter?

Tags: automation, jmeter, client-side, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm thinking on solution to automate client-side using Lighthouse or PageSpeed Insights in JMeter.

With PageSpeed Insights, using requests like

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=%2F&form_factor=mobile

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=%2F&form_factor=desktop

it is possible to get web-page which contains client-side metrics and parse out their values to variables:

URL_First Contentful Paint (FCP)

URL_First Input Delay (FID)

URL_Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)

URL_Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)

URL_Speed Index

URL_Time to Interactive

URL_Total Blocking Time

...

i.e. *URL_metric* - as variable name, where both *URL* and *metric* could change.

The question is, if I want to see the results statistics in JMeter "Summary Report" or "Aggregate Report" view for each combination of *URL* and *metric*, what is the best way to pass these variables names (*URL_metric*) as Label in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You could dump the saved values to a file in usual JMeter output format (JTL):

```
{timestamp},{duration},{sample_name},200,OK,thread_group_name 1-1,text,true,,0,0,20,65,null,0,0,0\n
```

Curly brackets denote placeholders.

You already have durations and sample names, timestamps do not matter in your case since you only wish to have aggregated results.

After saving the data to a file you could open it with **Summary Report** or **Aggregate Report**.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only variables URL_metric with their values - and the question is how to convert variables like URL_metric into "Label" (i.e. use them and only them instead of sample names)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get client-side metrics you will need a real browser, as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So in order to get client-side metrics from JMeter you need to kick off a real browser, for example take a look at [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework, check out [Mixing Selenium Into Your Load Scenario](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) for more details.

Once you have the metrics you can store them into JMeter's [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and plot them in [custom charts of the HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)

Comment: thank you. The question is only how to "say" to JMeter that all variables with following template URL_client-side_metric_parsed_from_PageSpeedInsights should be considered by JMeter as "Labels"?

Comment: ... and to be collected to csv (just each URL_metrics used instead of sample names, with values).